# How to parse html in node.js using jquery 2.1.3?

Tags: jquery, node.js, jsdom

I am trying to use node.js with jquery 2.1.3 and jsdom 4.0.4 to do web scraping. But I am running into problems running jquery module. This is the code

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var $ = require('jquery')(require("jsdom").jsdom().parentWindow); 
var http = require('http');
var request = require("request");


// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});


    var uri = "http://www.forever21.com/shop/ca/en/men-tees-tanks";

    request({
        uri: uri,
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            return console.error(error);
        }

        var f = $(body);

        res.write(body);

        res.end();
    });

});


// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Apps\Waerl\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:28
                                if ( !w.document ) {
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
    at module.exports (C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Apps\Waerl\node_modules\jquery\dist
\jquery.js:28:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Apps\Waerl\server.js:2:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jsdom 4.0.0 [switched](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/Changelog.md#400) from the non-standard parentWindow to the standard defaultView property on document.

Try with this:

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var $ = require('jquery')(require("jsdom").jsdom().defaultView); 
var http = require('http');
var request = require("request");


// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});


    var uri = "http://www.forever21.com/shop/ca/en/men-tees-tanks";

    request({
        uri: uri,
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            return console.error(error);
        }

        var f = $(body);

        res.write(body);

        res.end();
    });

});


// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```